# Flink: Appending Windowed Aggregates to Events

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I’m *very* new to Flink.  I read through the documentation and played with some sample code, but I’m struggling to get started with my requirements.

We want to use Flink to maintain windowed aggregates as part of a transaction monitoring application.  These would use sliding window definitions.  An example would be:  “Total amount for CASH transactions in the last 5 days”.   Here’s what I need my Flink application to do:
1.  Prepare for transaction processing by reading historical aggregates and building windows
2.  For each new transaction:
a.  Update the windowed aggregate with the new transaction data
b.  Find the window that matches the incoming time stamp and add the aggregate value to the transaction
c.  Send enhanced transaction (original fields + aggregates from matching window) to downstream processor via RabbitMQ or Kafka sink

For every transaction coming in, I want one (and only one) output that contains the original transaction fields plus the aggregates.

I see how to do the code to create the window assigner and the code that incrementally maintains the aggregates.  I’m not sure how I could join this back to the original transaction record, appending the aggregate values from the window that matches the transaction date stamp.  This seems like a join of some kind to me, but I don’t know how to implement in in Flink.

I’m hoping someone could reply with some simple code (or even pseudo code) to get me started on the “join”  part of the above data flow.  Please let me know if I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me how you intend to match the windows to the transactions, but in general terms you could stream the windowed aggregates and the transactions into a `CoFlatMap`, after having keyed both streams by whatever field you are going to join them on. You can use managed, keyed state to store the windowed aggregates, which you can then join to the transactions.

If the transactions are out-of-order and if you need to be more careful about time, then you might need to look at using a `CoProcessFunction` instead of `CoFlatMap` (the difference being that `CoProcessFunction` gives you access to a timer service). You might also need to use a `CoProcessFunction` if you need to use timers to clear out expired state for keys that are no longer relevant.

The Flink training includes an exercise on implementing a [Low-latency, Deterministic, Event Time Join](http://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/exercises/eventTimeJoin.html), but this may be much more complex than what you need, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks.  I plan to join by an entity key in the transaction (like account number).  I then want to select the aggregates to append by determining which window start/end date time the transaction time falls between.